# Google Shared Contacts API update the companywide contacts directory

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-admin-sdk, google-contacts-api

I'm creating a chrome extension, I'm using `chrome.identity.getAuthToken()` to get the access token. I'm authenticated with `firstName.lastName@company.com`. I set following scopes

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",
"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/",
"http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/"
```

Header has `GData-Version: 3.0` set.

I'm able to access my own contacts through `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/?access_token=...`

If I try to access the domain shared contacts through `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/company.com/full/?access_token=...` I get an error 403 with `Your client does not have permission to get URL /m8/feeds/contacts/company.com/full/ from this server`

My goal is to get an extension that is able to create shared contacts that can be accessed by everybody from the company.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My account didn't had the necessary read/write rights. It seems just superadmins are allowed to edit the domain shared contacts.

If I don't want to grant the user superadmin rights I would need to create a backend that takes care of the contact creation.

I would need to create a service account to impersonate superadmin level user, this account would update the contacts. All necessary information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)